# How to identify IMAGENAME with spaces in a batch file (tasklist)?

Tags: windows, batch-file, tasklist

Right now, I'm writing a batch file with a line that is identifying if a process is running from my process list.

The line I'm referring to:

```
FOR /F %%x IN ('tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq %EXE%"') DO IF %%x == %EXE% goto ProcessFound
```

EXE is defined beforehand as EXE= My Process Here.exe

My batch file works with normal processes, but as you can see with My Process Here.exe, there is a space between My and Process and Here.exe and this is not recognizable.

Is there any way to fix this? The process I am looking for has spaces and I can't change the process name as the program it is related to will not run if I do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "exe=7+ Taskbar Tweaker.exe"
FOR /F %%x IN ('tasklist ^|FINDSTR /i /b /L /c:"%EXE%"') DO IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 goto ProcessFound1
ECHO "%exe%" not found
GOTO again
:Processfound1
ECHO "%exe%" found!
:again
SET "exe=I dont exist.exe"
FOR /F %%x IN ('tasklist ^|FINDSTR /i /b /L /c:"%EXE%"') DO IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 goto ProcessFound1
ECHO "%exe%" not found
GOTO :eof
:Processfound2
ECHO "%exe%" found!
GOTO :EOF
```

This may work for you. You'd need to fix the process names of course.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "exe=My Process Here.exe"

    set "processFound="
    for /f "tokens=5 delims=," %%a in ('
        tasklist /fi "imagename eq %exe%" /fo:csv /nh
    ') do set "processFound=1"

    if defined processFound (
        echo %exe% is running
    ) else (
        echo %exe% is NOT running
    )
```

The `tasklist` will retrieve the list of processes for for the indicated image name and in csv format, without headers.

There are two options: the process is not running and then there are not csv records in the output, or the process is running and there are csv records in the ouptut.

The `for` command will try to tokenize the output of `tasklist` and retrieve the 5th token in the line using commas as delimiters.

If the output from `tasklist` is a csv record, this token will exist, the replaceable parameter will get data and the code in the `do` clause will be executed. If the output is not a csv record, the token will not exist, and the code in the `do` clause will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the prior answers worked for me for identifying imagenames with embedded spaces.  What did work for me was to use "delims=tab" where tab is the actual tab character as in:

```
FOR /F "delims=tab" %%X IN ('tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq !EXE!"') DO (...
```

The resulting %%X will either be the entire tasklist entry corresponding to the !EXE! imagename, if found, or "INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria", if not found, that can be acted on by something like:

```
    SET TASKLINE=%%X
    IF "!TASKLINE!"=="!TASKLINE:No tasks are running=!" (
        ECHO !EXE! FOUND IN !TASKLINE!
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO !EXE! NOT FOUND IN !TASKLINE!))
```